# username only login redirects to different pages based on text input

Tags: javascript, redirect, authentication

I am trying to make a login form for my site that includes only a username and redirects to different pages based on text input. For example, if User A inputs their username, the page will redirect to `mysite.com/1234`. If User B inputs a different username, the page will redirect to `mysite.com/5678`. And so on. I'll have approximately 20 instances/users. I am trying to accomplish this without PHP. Any help is appreciated, thanks

As of right now, this is the code I was using for a full login page. But seeing how insecure that is, is there a way for me to edit it to just include a username field that will just redirect to where I need it to?

```
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function Login(){
           var done = 0;
            var username = document.login.username.value;
            usernam = username.toLowerCase();
            var password = document.login.password.value;
            password = password.toLowerCase();
            if (username == "user1" && password == "1234") {     
                window.location = "page1";     
                done = 1; 
            }

            if (username == "user2" && password == "5678") { 
                window.location = "page2";
                done = 1; 
            }
        }
    </SCRIPT>

<BODY>
    <center>
        <form name=login>
            <table width=225 cellpadding=5>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2>
                        <center><font size="+2"><b>Doctor Log In</b></font> 
                        </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=text name=username>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=password name=password>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2 align=center>
                        <input type=button value="Login" onClick="Login()" )>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
    <p>
        <center>
```

Comment: `"Any help is appreciated"` - Help with what?  Where are you stuck?  If you have 20 known values and a user input value, then it sounds like you need to write some comparison logic.  Such as a `switch` block or a series of `if` blocks.  Or perhaps a data structure of the 20 options and the input value is used to select behavior from that structure.  What isn't working?

Comment: @Kmeixner - edited to show what I've tried so far, my apologies

Comment: @David I've added code that has been tried so far, sorry about that

Comment: @mystique01: Well, you can "edit it to just include a username field" by removing the password field.  And, of course, removing the references to the password in the code (since there'd be no value input by the user).  What are you asking?  How to edit the file that has this code?  Again, what did you *actually try to do* and how is that attempt not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a kind of router function in JavaScript like this.

```js
function redir(which) {
  users = {
    "abc": 123,
    "def": 456,
    "ghi": 789
    // and so on
  }
  location.href = users[which.username] + '.htm'
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return redir(this)">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

To this, you can add username and password, verify them, and then either change the location, etc. It is better to keep the JS separate for security reasons!